# Replace a blank p tag from a string using jquery

Tags: jquery, replace

I have a string like below

```
<p> Hello test</p>
<p><br data-mce-bogus="1"></p>
<p> Hello test</p>
<p><br data-mce-bogus="1"></p>
<p> Hello test</p>
<p><br data-mce-bogus="1"></p>
<p> Hello test</p>
<p><br data-mce-bogus="1"></p>
<p> Hello test</p>
<p><br data-mce-bogus="1"></p>
<p> Hello test</p>
```

I want to remove `<p><br data-mce-bogus="1"></p>` from the string but the below code is not workin

```
$jobdesc = '<p> Hello test</p><p><br data-mce-bogus="1"></p><p> Hello test</p><p><br data-mce-bogus="1"></p><p> Hello test</p><p><br data-mce-bogus="1"></p><p> Hello test</p><p><br data-mce-bogus="1"></p><p> Hello test</p><p><br data-mce-bogus="1"></p><p> Hello test</p>';
$jobdesc = $jobdesc.replace('/<p><br data-mce-bogus="1"></p>/g', '');
```

Please help!.

Comment: replace it with nothing? if so can do `if ($('p').text().length > 0) {$(this).remove()}`

Comment: There is no [jquery] involvement here. This is a plain JS problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a string instead of a RegExp to replace the contents. Also you need to escape the `/` in the RegExp.

The following works fine:

```js
$jobdesc = '<p> Hello test</p><p><br data-mce-bogus="1"></p><p> Hello test</p><p><br data-mce-bogus="1"></p><p> Hello test</p><p><br data-mce-bogus="1"></p><p> Hello test</p><p><br data-mce-bogus="1"></p><p> Hello test</p><p><br data-mce-bogus="1"></p><p> Hello test</p>';
console.log($jobdesc.replace(/<p><br data-mce-bogus="1"><\/p>/g, ''));
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using string('inside this') remove '' this and put escape(/)  it in RegExp

```js
$jobdesc = '<p> Hello test</p><p><br data-mce-bogus="1"></p><p> Hello test</p><p><br data-mce-bogus="1"></p><p> Hello test</p><p><br data-mce-bogus="1"></p><p> Hello test</p><p><br data-mce-bogus="1"></p><p> Hello test</p><p><br data-mce-bogus="1"></p><p> Hello test</p>';
$jobdesc = $jobdesc.replace(/<p><br data-mce-bogus=\"1\"><\/p>/g, '');
alert($jobdesc);
```